# My Async/Await (ES2017) Function Isn't Running Sequentially?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm to get my head around `async`/`await` but having trouble getting the steps inside the function to run *sequentially*, **and** wait for each other to finish.

Basically I'm trying to get it to fire off `myProm`, wait a second, fire it off again.

What am I not getting?

```
function myProm() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('promise in one seconds');
        }, 1000))
    })
}

async function myFunc() {
    try {
        await myProm();
        await myProm();
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

myFunc()
```

Comment: `async`/`await` isn't ES7, it's ES8. But it's easier if you use the now-official year-based nomenclature (adopted for ES2015, aka ES6). `async`/`await` is an ES2017 feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `resolve` **right away**. You should do it **inside** the `setTimeout` callback:

```
function myProm() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('promise in one seconds');
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    })
}
```

(Or the `setTimeout` could be `setTimeout(resolve, 1000)` if you just want to call resolve.)

Live Example:

```js
function myProm() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('promise in one seconds');
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('resolved');
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    })
}

async function myFunc() {
    try {
        await myProm();
        await myProm();
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

myFunc();
```

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder i've never seen `resolve()`called by itself like that before. I had assumed `resolve(*whatever i want to pass back to the promise*)` was the only way to do it. But this is pretty cool!

Comment: @Aid: What you pass `resolve` is the value the promise should take. In `resolve();`, it's (effectively) the value `undefined`. Your options are to pass it a thenable (in which case the promise will be slaved to the outcome of that thenable) or a non-thenable value (the promise will be resolved with that value). (If "thenable" is unfamiliar: https://promisesaplus.com)

Answer (score 1):

Your `myProm` function's promise calls `resolve()` immediately, so it doesn't actually wait for anything.

You need to only call `resolve()` once you want your promise to resolve (inside the callback).